# error: index.js: .plugins[0] must be a string, object, function

Tags: node.js, react-native, mobile-application

I see some other questions posted similar to mine but they had to do with a .babelrc file which I either do not have or don't see in my project. I have a .babel.config.js file which I feel is the equivalent to that. However, I am getting the following error when trying to load my React Native application, can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Note, I am using ExpoGo to load my app and using something like

```
npx yarn add expo
```

along with

```
npx expo start
```

as how I initialize my app...

error: index.js: .plugins[0] must be a string, object, function

Below is files for your reference, please let me know if you need other files to see.

index.js:

```
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';

import App from './App';

// registerRootComponent calls AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => App);
// It also ensures that whether you load the app in Expo Go or in a native build,
// the environment is set up appropriately
registerRootComponent(App);
```

registerRootComponent.d.ts:

```
    import '../Expo.fx';
    import * as React from 'react';
    type InitialProps = {
        exp: {
            notification?: any;
            manifestString?: string;
            [key: string]: any;
        };
        shell?: boolean;
        shellManifestUrl?: string;
        [key: string]: any;
    };
    export default function registerRootComponent<P extends InitialProps>(component: React.ComponentType<P>): void;
    export {};
    //# sourceMappingURL=registerRootComponent.d.ts.map
```

babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo']
  };
};
```

app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "HalaFinds",
    "slug": "HalaFinds",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "splash": {
      "image": "./splash.png",
      "backgroundColor": "#4FC123"
    }
  }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "halafinds",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^18.0.4",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.19.4",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",
    "axios": "^1.5.1",
    "expo": "^50.0.6",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~12.3.2",
    "expo-image-picker": "^14.5.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "^12.5.0",
    "expo-localization": "~14.3.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.1",
    "expo-sqlite": "^11.6.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "hoist-non-react-statics": "~2.5.5",
    "lottie-react-native": "^6.3.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.3",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-event-listeners": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-feather": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.5.1",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-localize": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^17.1.0",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "1.1.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.14.0",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.2.9",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.6",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.10",
    "react-native-webview": "^13.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```